# how to show device dialing pad on number when click/select on number in mobile application

Tags: jquery, html, css, numbers, phone-call

We develop hybrid mobile application.

In this application When click/select on number it should be going to show on dialing pad in a device.

How to do what steps we have to follow ?

```js
$(function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|Android.*Mobile)/i))
    {
        $('a[data-tel]').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('href', 'tel:' + $(this).data('tel'));
        });
    }
})
```

```html
 <table>
        <tr><td style="padding:2px">Traiff</td><td style="padding:8px"><a data-tel="974-4433665588" href="tel:974-4433665588" data-rel="external" style="color:#333946 !important">974-4433665588</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="padding:2px">Divil</td><td style="padding:8px"><a data-tel="974-4433665588" style="color:#333946 !important">974-4433665588</a></td></tr>
        </table>
```

this is my app link
                                                                               http://desktop-tsrno5e:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/index.html?webpage=/datepicker/apps/services/preview/ww/android/1.0/&platform=android

Answer (score 0):

simply use [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function

```
$(function(){
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|Android.*Mobile)/i)) {
    $('a[data-tel]').click(function(){
       $(this).prop('href', 'tel:' + $(this).data('tel'));
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: i think u are missing something here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/mca7aaqk/

Comment: do we need to add any permission in android manifest.xml file

Comment: i don't think so try by removing navigator.userAgent condition just for testing and tell me

Comment: if(match(/(iPhone|Android.*Mobile)/i)

Comment: Noooo i mean try by removing mobile detection

Comment: yes that is also we did but it should not open dail pad

Comment: can you share your app link ?

Comment: i think we need to add permission for open the dailpad in manifest.xml file

Comment: may be try why you waiting for than :D

Comment: have you try on desktop emulator ? check function is working or not

Comment: i given my app link in question please see

Comment: yaa oky, but i saw most of the sites in that sites saying we need add permission for dailing pad but i added it is also not working

Comment: don't know than waiting for someone else

Comment: i got it solution , this is the solution  Change <access origin="*"/>
To <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="true"> in config.xml

Comment: i need to iphone and windows environment also how to do